# group of aligned equations, trying to get code to compile correctly

Tags: align

Can I ask how to get the following code to compile correctly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \phantom{$\implies$}
    &\begin{aligned}
     \mathllap{ } &= $\vdash \Box_{N} (\forall k \phi(k))$\\
     \end{aligned}\\
    &\begin{aligned}
     \mathllap{$\implies$} &= $\vdash \forall k \Box_{C+2N+\mathrm{log}_{2} \hspace{0.1 cm} k} \phi(k)$\\
     \mathllap{$\implies$) &= $\vdash \forall k \Box_{\mathcal{O}\mathrm{log}_{2} \hspace{0.1 cm} k} \phi(k)$\\
     \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the `\phantom` and the `\mathllap`'s? They seem irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align` is typeset in math mode, so using `$` inside it is wrong (and also in the argument to `\mathllap`.

There are strange equals signs that I guess are due to a misunderstanding. In `align`, `&` denotes a point of alignment (the separation for columns, actually), which is often followed by `=`, but not necessarily.

I present three realizations, each without `\implies`. In the third one, the main block is centered due to `\mathllap`, but it doesn't seem really important (just compare the outputs). I recommend `\Rightarrow`, which is less prominent.

Final notes: `\log` is the right command to use, not `\mathrm{log}`; I also added parentheses around the argument to `\mathcal{O}`; using `\,` after `\forall <variable>` is likely better.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\vdash \Box_{N} (\forall k \, \phi(k)) \\
\Longrightarrow{}
&\vdash \forall k \, \Box_{C+2N+\log_{2}k} \phi(k) \\
\Longrightarrow{}
&\vdash \forall k \, \Box_{\mathcal{O}(\log_{2} k)} \phi(k) 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\vdash \Box_{N} (\forall k \, \phi(k)) \\
\Rightarrow{}
&\vdash \forall k \, \Box_{C+2N+\log_{2}k} \phi(k) \\
\Rightarrow{}
&\vdash \forall k \, \Box_{\mathcal{O}(\log_{2} k)} \phi(k) 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\vdash \Box_{N} (\forall k \, \phi(k)) \\
\mathllap{\Rightarrow{}}
&\vdash \forall k \, \Box_{C+2N+\log_{2}k} \phi(k) \\
\mathllap{\Rightarrow{}}
&\vdash \forall k \, \Box_{\mathcal{O}(\log_{2} k)} \phi(k) 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've just cleared the errors only, not checking the output, hence the output should be as you wish:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \phantom{\implies}
    &\begin{aligned}
    \mathllap{ } &= \vdash \Box_{N} (\forall k \phi(k))
     \end{aligned}\\
    &\begin{aligned}
     \mathllap{\implies} &= \vdash \forall k \Box_{C+2N+\log_{2} k} \phi(k)\\
     \mathllap{\implies} &= \vdash \forall k \Box_{\mathcal{O}\log_{2}  k} \phi(k)
     \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to fix `\mathrm{log}` as well and there is no need for the last ``\\``

Comment: @daleif Have updated, thanks, if any further change needs, please feel free to modify

Comment: I removed the `\hspace` as `\log` gives proper spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your desired output, but it seems you are misusing the `align` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 &= \vdash \Box_{N} (\forall k \phi(k))\\
\implies &= \vdash \forall k \Box_{C+2N+\log_{2} k} \phi(k)\\
\implies &= \vdash \forall k \Box_{\mathcal{O}\log_{2} k} \phi(k)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```